# Simple Android App - Out of Memory error when running on smartphone

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am fairly new to Android Studio and I  try to make a simple app. Random Images should appear after a button is clicked. The next cannot be one that was already showed.

I have two classes. The MainActivity and RandomCardDraw.

When I run the app in the AVD Emulator, it does not crash. But sometimes I get the information "Skipped frames". When I run it on my Samsung S6 the app crashes everytime when I try to get the second image. In Android I can see a Out of Memory Error.

The images are between 100-200kb and I have about 18 of them.

Maybe you can see where I get my perfomance Issues from?

Here is my Code:

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView cardView;
    Button nextCard;
    RandomCardDraw2 game1 = new RandomCardDraw2();
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        game1.createRandomCardList();
        gameStart();


    }

    public void gameStart()
    {
        cardView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        nextCard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextCard);
        nextCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                if (counter < 19)
                {
                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(game1.drawnCards.get(counter), "drawable", getPackageName());
                    cardView.setImageResource(id);
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And RandowmCardDraw:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Random;  


public class RandomCardDraw2
{
    ArrayList<String> drawnCards = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rndInt = new Random();

    public void createRandomCardList()
    {
        boolean gameType = true;
        int counter;
        if (gameType == true)
        {
            counter = 19;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                String cardId = "card" + rndInt.nextInt(18 + 1);
                drawnCards.add(cardId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 23;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                String cardId = "card" + rndInt.nextInt(18 + 1);
                drawnCards.add(cardId);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When the app is opened. The ArrayList with cards is filled randomly. And then when the user clicks the button, the next card appears. As I said, on my smartphone the app crashes when I want to get the second image.

The ErrorCode:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.kajet.shutupanddrink, PID: 18109
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 192000012 byte allocation with 16775360 free bytes and 69MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4215)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
                  at com.example.kajet.shutupanddrink.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much!

Comment: please post your stacktrace...!

Comment: Hi shobhit, thanks for the hint. I edited it and put the error code in my question. I hope that is what you meant by stacktrace!

Comment: `images are between 100-200kb`. What kind of images are they? And what is their resolution?

Comment: Read your stacktrace. You can clearly see that its starts with OnClick() and that `cardView.setImageResource(id);` is the culprit because it uses BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream which leeds to a Bitmap that would become too big for available memory. (Read stacktrace from bottom too top).

Comment: `on my smartphone the app crashes`. Your app does not have to crash if you catch the OutOfMemoryError. You can display a Toast() to the user with e.getMessage() info.

Comment: @greenapps The images are .png's with a resolution is 1500x2000px. Is it possible to avoid that the Bitmap eats so much RAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add these in your manifest these lines:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

@your manifest.xml would like be:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test it tomorrow. From looking at the statement, does this just allow the app to get more RAM? I mean I would like to have an efficient app that does not eat 500MB of RAM. When 1 card is drawn, my phone shows 200MB of RAM usage for the app....

Comment: Actually android:largeHeap is the instrument for increasing your allocated memory to app.

There is no clear definition of the need to use this flag. If you need more memory - Android provides you with a tool to increase it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. At least it works now. As my error is coming from the BitmapFactory, would it be possible to recycle() the Bitmap to save memory? And if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: use Caching Bitmaps technique:https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if you find it useful?