# Android Picasso, using cache

Tags: android, picasso

I have a photo gallery(list) in my app, and I use the Picasso library to display images.

But while using the app, the app crashed sometimes because of the Out of memory error. And after searching a web, I found the solution which is to disable using cache for Picasso library.

```
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE, MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
```

After disabled using cache, the error is gone, but I think there is some smart way to using the cache.

Is there any guild line for using Picasso cache? like if the memory usage is closing to limit then, disable the using cache?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the Out of memory means that the application's memory limit is reached, maybe you try to load a really big image, or the memory for your app is not enough.
Maybe the top answer in this question can help you [Simple Android App - Out of Memory error when running on smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053173/simple-android-app-out-of-memory-error-when-running-on-smartphone)