# Can't Launch Android Studio Error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, oracle, flutter, android-studio, dart

I can't open my Android Studio. I've tried to uninstall and install it again, but still the same problem. No error is given when I tried to launch the app. When I run studio.bat in the Command Prompt it shows me this error :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin>studio.bat

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at gnu.trove.TLongHashSet.rehash(TLongHashSet.java:162)
        at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:285)
        at gnu.trove.TLongHashSet.add(TLongHashSet.java:146)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClasspathCache$LoaderDataBuilder.addPossiblyDuplicateNameEntry(ClasspathCache.java:83)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.buildData(JarLoader.java:160)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.initLoader(ClassPath.java:256)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.initLoaders(ClassPath.java:215)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getLoaderSlowPath(ClassPath.java:166)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getLoader(ClassPath.java:145)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getResource(ClassPath.java:113)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:335)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:326)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:108)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)

-----
JRE 1.8.0_281-b09 amd64 by Oracle Corporation
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @abbasjafary nope

Answer (score 1):

add these in your manifest these lines:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

@your manifest.xml would like to be:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

For more information please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053173/simple-android-app-out-of-memory-error-when-running-on-smartphone) link.

Or please make sure you have set enough memory in the project's gradle.properties. The default was changed from 1g to 512m in 5.0 and you can open gradle.properties file with notepad

Comment: Hi, I can't launch the Android Studio, not the app that I'm making. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MichaelRenoPratamaSetyawan I edited my answer and I hope this work for you,
How much RAM is in your computer?

Comment: Hi, my laptop has 8gb of RAM but I dont know how much my RAM usage.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 10, anything else?

Comment: Right-click on the taskbar => Task manager => Process Tab => Sort the below list with memory for seeing memory usage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228730/discussion-between-michael-reno-pratama-setyawan-and-abbas-jafary).

Answer (score 0):

Check your device (mobile or emulator's) memory size.
Some times this may happen when memory is not set for install and extract the app.